# Regular Expression, match url without "http://" and any other "/"

Tags: java, regex, url, expression

I looked around for a while, but probably I can't "Google" with the proper keywords.. so I'm here.
I need to match an url stripping out protocol to first /

**Target:** match the first substring from http:// to first / (maybe last / don't exist) or to the end
And here come a problem:

i wrote this regex

> (?<=//)(.*?)(?=/)

but this regex matches only url with at least 1 '/' in the end excluding the protocol..

here some url to be matched:

- http://**www.google.com**/ (matched by my regex)
- http://**www.google.com**
- https://**www.google**
- xxx://**www.google.com**/hello/bleh blah....../
- xxx://**google.com**
- **google.com**/blah/hello.php?x=11_x.hi

Comment: what about

((?:[a-z][a-z\.\d\-]+)\.(?:[a-z][a-z\-]+))(?![\w\.])

?

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:\w+://)?([\w.-]+)/?.*$
```

(double backslashes for Java)
seems to work on all your examples, including a simple `www.google.com`

Answer (score 0):

Something like...

```
^(https?:\/\/)?([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6})\/
```

I saw this in a book I had.  That should account for a variable http/https, disallow whitespace, and probably stop at the first slash.

Comment if I did this wrong.

Comment: well i needed to cut off http:// too
i maked this in the end
((?:[a-z][a-z\.\d\-]+)\.(?:[a-z][a-z\-]+))(?![\w\.])
ty for suggestion anyway

Answer (score 0):

This is working for all your example but the last:

```
(?<=//)[^/\\s]+
```

`[^/\\s]` is a negated character class matching every character except `/` and `\s` (whitespace, e.g. a space, tab or newline characters)

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?331j3)

**What will not work is the last row. How do you want to decide what is a link? If I make the first part optional, it will match on every character except `/` and whitespaces.**

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have the right answer, but you're missing the possibility of not having a trailing "/".  Try this:

```
(?<=//)(.*?)(?=/|$)
```