# Regular expression for finding URL in Java String

Tags: java, regex, string, url

How do you modify the following regex:

```
String URLpattern   = "((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|Unsure|http):((//)|(\\\\))+[\\w\\d:#@%/;$()~_?\\+-=\\\\\\.&]*)"
```

with one that takes into account ALL the following URL forms?

```
http://www.website.com
https://www.website.com
www.website.com
website.com
http://website.com
https://website.com
```

---

EDIT:
There are a bunch of already proposed solutions to the problem. I can list some of them:

- [Regular expression to match URLs in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163360/regular-expresion-to-match-urls-in-java)
- [Regex to matches a url with or without http in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017154/regex-to-matches-a-url-with-or-without-http-in-java) (nice since explained, however not working in my code)
- [Regular Expression, match url without "http://" and any other "/"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704362/regular-expression-match-url-without-http-and-any-other)

However, although I tried all of them too, none of them is proposing an explanation of how and why the expression works. Thus, whenever there is a malfunctioning (and to me, a malfunctioning was happening in urls in the form `website.com` and `http://website.com`), it becomes difficult for newbies (like me ;) ) to apply any modification or understand what is going on when there is a failure.
A well explained solution is always better than a solution made by others and not replicable in the next time =)

Comment: Why did I get so many downvotes? I mean: I looked for other questions related to this topic but none of them is offering a functioning solution... If you think this is not a good question you should require to close it :)

Comment: We want to see effort. If you've done research, show it and explain why it doesn't help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your list of websites, the following regex will do the trick:

`(https?://)?(www\.)?\w+\.com`

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/iS2hV1)</kbd>

Comment: I know the feeling you get when upvotes don't count after reaching 20 upvotes lol

Comment: @DavidWallace, Thank you, Answer corrected. The /g might have tagged along by mistake when I was copying. from regex101.com

Comment: And also: I guess Java requires two backslashes

Comment: @Eleanore Well, not exactly.  Having a regexp in a String literal means you have to double the backslashes, because of the rules about how String literals work.  If your regexp came from somewhere else (like being read in from a file),  you wouldn't have to double the backslashes.

Comment: @Eleanore, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it works fine.TESTED with all your URLs!

```
private static final String URL_PATTERN = "(@)?(href=')?(HREF=')?(HREF=\")?(href=\")?(http://)?(https://)?" +
        "[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-]+(\\.\\w[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-]+)+(/[#&\\n\\-=?\\+\\%/\\.\\w]+)?";

private Pattern urlPattern =Pattern.compile(URL_PATTERN);

public boolean isURL(String url)
{
    boolean mat = urlPattern.matcher(url.trim().replace(" ","")).matches();
    return urlPattern.matcher(url.replace(" ","")).matches();
}
```